# How do create an internal remote repository of all the jars my project uses?

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, repository

Currently, I'm relying on many external remote repositories, but the requirements for a project that I am working on state that it must be an internal repository. Most of the jars will be identical to the external repositories, and there will be some custom ones as well.

How do I do this? I noticed on the Maven website, it says not to rsync:// the whole directory. I don't intend to do that at all, but I would like to grab about 30 jars.

If there is a way to quickly copy the ones I want over to my internal repository, will they just work out of the box, or will I have to do anything special?

Answer (score 2):

Set up a local maven repository application and have it [proxy](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) central (and any other repositories you require).